# BibTeX doesn't work

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a problem with my bibliography. I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib} 

\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\begin{document}

some text here \citep[see][]{ODIG}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

I have done my bibliography in a different document and compiled it with BibTeX, but it doesn't work. In fact when I compile (two times) the result is:

> (see:?)

references
(nothing)

I used

@ARTICLE {ODIG, 
title={Oligarchy, democracy, inequality and growth}, 
author={Bouguignon,Francois and Verdier, Thierry}, 
journal={Journal of Development Economics}, 
volume={62}, 
issue={},
 pages={285--313}, 
year={2000}, }

There is no error in .blg, there are that warnings

Paper.tex 66 Package natbib Warning: Citation ODIG' on page 2 undefined on input line 66.

Paper.bbl 3 Package natbib Warning: Empty thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

Paper.tex Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Welcome, this is a common problem. Please read [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: Please post the contents of the ODIG entry in the file `biblio.bib`. Please also advise if there's an error or warning message in the .blg ("BibTeX log") file.

Comment: @ARTICLE
{ODIG,
 title={Oligarchy, democracy, inequality and growth},
 author={Bouguignon,Francois and Verdier, Thierry},
 journal={Journal of Development Economics},
 volume={62},
 issue={},
  pages={285--313},
 year={2000},
 }

There is no error in .blg, there are that warmings 
Paper.tex
66
Package natbib Warning: Citation `ODIG' on page 2 undefined on input line 66.
Paper.bbl
3
Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.
Paper.tex

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

Comment: @M.S. Please add that information to the question, that keeps the informatioin in one place for the helpers to find. And eerytime you edit, the uestion is pulled back to the top of the list of questions. The edit button is in the left bottom part of your question.

Comment: Please double-check the spelling of the file name that contains the bib entry. Is it `biblio.bib`? And, do check that the file `biblio.bib` can be found by BibTeX. (FWIW, I encounter no problems when I compile your code using `biblio.bib` as the file name.)

Comment: I have solved. The problem was in the file, i have saved the file .tex and not in .bib
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by an incorrect filename extension ("tex" instead of "bib") for the bibliography file.